# What is IP binding in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to learn how to implement replication in mongodb.

I have gone through the [mongodb docs on the same topic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) and I understand most of it. However I do not really understand everything about [ip binding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp)

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) the `bindip` is

> The hostnames and/or IP addresses and/or full Unix domain socket paths
>   on which mongos or mongod should listen for client connections.

According to the same [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.port) `net.port` is:

> The TCP port on which the MongoDB instance listens for client
>   connections.

I can see the differences from the two definitions and I understand `net.port` well enough. But I do not understand what [net.bindIp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) really is and how it works. So here are my questions

1. What is the difference between socket paths and TCP ports in regard to mongodb listening for client connections?
2. The docs say that when  [net.bindIpAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIpAll) is set to true: "the mongos or mongod instance binds to all IPv4 addresses (i.e. 0.0.0.0)." Where do this "IPv4 addresses" come from? Why are they many? What is the advantage of binding to all of them?
3. Why not just use [port](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.port) to access my mongodb instance why do I need bind an ip address?

Comment: Say I have a computer with 2 network cards.  One is connected to the outside world the other is connected to my local network.  I use iptables to control traffic.  It's probably never a good idea to put a database on a firewall server but for the purposes of illustration lets say I installed MongoDB on this computer.

Comment: For security purposes I do not want MongoDB to listen for traffic on the external network card, so instead I bind to the network card IP address for my internal network.  Now (assuming no firewall rules are preventing connections) I can access this database from my internal network but not from the internet itself.

Comment: If I were to bind to 0.0.0.0 anyone on the internet could connect to this MongoDB installation as well as computers in my private network.

Comment: when considering replication in a development world you probably just want to see it work.  In this case binding to all adapters using 0.0.0.0 is very do-able.  I do this all the time.  In fact, in a development environment I don't secure the database at all.  The replication set members do not use any type of internal authentication.  They freely talk to one-another for replication.  But in a real production environment I recommend using internal auth using x509, or keyfiles at a bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why was the question down-voted? Hope you gave an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Hi @YulePale - I did not downvote.  Actually, I never downvote.  I don't understand why people downvote with no comment.  I upvoted it back to zero - LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MongoDB the configuration item net.bindIp allows the administrator to specify which network adapter the MongoDB process should listen for traffic on (by IP Address).  For a multi-homed system (multiple network cards) traffic can be managed by specifying the IP Address related to a specific network card for both performance and security.  If the IP address 0.0.0.0 is specified then all network adapters will be used.  To bind to all adapters using IPv6 then specify ::,0.0.0.0 instead.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/ for details.

The advice I have always received is to NEVER use a hostname or DNS name, but instead ALWAYS use an IP Address.

Comment: Why use an IP address? In the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/#replica-set-configuration) they say: “TIP
When possible, use a logical DNS hostname instead of an ip address, particularly when configuring replica set members or sharded cluster members. The use of logical DNS hostnames avoids configuration changes due to ip address changes”. What is the advantage of using an IP address?

Comment: @YulePale - when adding members to a replica set you can specify a host or ip address.  This is similar but different when setting the options in the config file for bindIp.  The recommendation I have received for setting up replica set members is always add hosts by host name, but for ipConfig always use ip address not host name.  I have not received a good answer why, just that it was stressed...